# Shutting down via command line causes the system to hang on the shutdown screen

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, lubuntu

I am using Lubuntu 11.10, and the commands:

```
sudo shutdown
```

and

```
sudo halt
```

do not shutdown my system. Instead the computer hangs at the shutdown screen that appears just before powering off. From that point on it just does nothing. Any ideas on why this happens?

Comment: What version of Lubuntu are you running? Does shutting down from the power menu on the upper-right corner of the screen also not work?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding that "halt" means exactly the behavior you're observing - all the processes are terminated and the machine is halted (i.e. "stays stuck ... just before shutting down") - which was the only possible behaviour in old days when machines had no ACPI capabilities - first you halt the machine and then flip the power switch manually.

A related command called `poweroff` gracefully terminates all processes and then issues an ACPI call which powers the machine off.

However, as Rinzwind points out, the exact behaviour of `halt` command can be changed by editing `/etc/default/halt`, so it is possible to make it to behave like `poweroff`.

Try

```
sudo poweroff
```

or

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

Comment: well, I've been using halt for many years, and it turns off the PC here.

Comment: @Ysangkok: Check out answers to this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/191537/shutdown-what-is-difference-between-power-off-and-halt - also, `man shutdown` clearly implies that there's a difference between `poweroff` and `halt` although it's not very clear what the difference is, and also for `shutdown -h now` it says "Requests that the system be either halted or powered off after it has  been  brought  down, with the choice as to which left up to the system". So, I suppose, `halt` command may or may not power the system off, depending on the phase of the moon.

Answer (score 1):

Check the file `/etc/default/halt` This file contains a variable setting that tells `halt` how it should behave.

```
OPTIONS

   The following variables can be set.

   HALT   If set to poweroff the system will be powered down after it  has
          been brought down. This is the default.
          If  set to halt the system will only be halted after it has been
          brought down. What exactly this means depends on your hardware.

   NETDOWN
          Setting this to no prevents  shutdown  from  shutting  down  the
          network  intefaces.   This  is  necessary  to  use  Wake-On-Lan.
          Setting it to yes causes shutdown to also bring down the network
          interfaces  (and  thus  prevent  the machine from being woken up
          remotely).
```

`HALT` is probably set to `halt` instead of `poweroff`.

From my system:  `more /etc/default/halt`

```
# Default behaviour of shutdown -h / halt. Set to "halt" or "poweroff".
HALT=poweroff
```

Answer (score 0):

I always use `shutdown -h now`.

Answer (score 0):

Halt and poweroff

```
sudo shutdown -hP now
```

Comment: Why not just `sudo shutdown -P now` ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple thing to do is follow the directions below. This is what I have done
and everything started working okay now for me and some of my co-workers' workstation/Laptop.

If you are using Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10, and 12.04, open command line and run the following command:

```
$ gksudo gedit /etc/default/halt
```

Now that you have your Vi or Gedit - Editor open, add this below in your file as shown `INIT_HALT = POWEROFF`. Hope this helps you as it has for me.

#### Halt Script:

```
# Default behaviour of shutdown -h / halt. Set to "halt" or "poweroff".
HALT=poweroff
INIT_HALT = POWEROFF
```